# Solving a second-order matrix differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}+Ax=0$ where $A$ is a matrix and $$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=\left(\frac{d^2 x_1}{dt^2},\frac{d^2 x_2}{dt^2},\ldots,\frac{d^2 x_n}{dt^2}\right)^T\text{ for }x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n).$$

I know the solution is $x=\cos(\sqrt{A}(t-t_0))x_0+(\sqrt{A})^{-1}\sin(\sqrt{A}(t-t_0))\dot{x}_0$, but I have no idea why this is.

How would I go about deriving this solution? The literature I have looked at simply states the solution with little or no explanation.

Comment: I dont know if it works, but you can introduce an auxillary vector $y = (y_1,y_2,...,y_n)^T= \dot x$. Then you have a system of first order equations.

Comment: Like $\dfrac d{dt} (x\,\,y)^T = \begin{pmatrix}  0&I \\ A&0\end{pmatrix} (x\,\,y)^T$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let  $A$ be diagonalisable ($A=P^{-1}A_dP$ with $A_d$ diagonal). Then the equation $\vec{x}''+A\vec{x}=0$ can be rewritten as $P\vec{x}''+A_dP\vec{x}=0$. Denote $\vec{y}=P\vec{x}$, then
$$\vec{y}''+A_d\vec{y}=0.$$
But this is equivalent to $n$ independent scalar ODEs
$$ y_k''+\lambda_k y_k=0,$$
where $\lambda_k$ denotes the eigenvalue of $A$ standing in the $k$th place of the diagonal of $A_d$. Their solutions are
$$y_k(t)=\cos\sqrt{\lambda_k}(t-t_0)\,y_k(t_0)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_k}}\sin\sqrt{\lambda_k}(t-t_0)\,y'_k(t_0).$$
Or, in matrix form
$$ \vec{y}(t)=\cos \sqrt{A_d}(t-t_0)\,\vec{y}(t_0)+\sqrt{A_d}^{-1}\sin \sqrt{A_d}(t-t_0)\,\vec{y}\,'(t_0).
$$
Now using that $\vec{x}=P^{-1}\vec{y}$ and that $P^{-1}f(A_d)P=f(A)$ for any function $f$, we obtain the quoted result.

Comment: Thanks. What about in the inhomogeneous case?
I believe the answer is
$x=\cos(\sqrt{A}(t-t_0))x_0+(\sqrt{A})^{-1}\sin(\sqrt{A}(t-t_0))\dot{x}_0
+(\sqrt{A})^{-1}\int_{t_0}^t\sin\left(\sqrt{A}(t-s)\right)f(s)ds$, 

but this can't be derived in the same way since we would have a $Pf(t)$ on the RHS.

Comment: It will be fine for the very same reason. You will have the non-homogeneity $\vec{F}=P\vec{f}$ for $\vec{y}$, then solving for $\vec{y}$, coming back to $\vec{x}$ and using $P^{-1}\mu(A_d)P=\mu(A)$, you will get something like that.