# Solve the second order equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2} = \begin{bmatrix} -5 & -1 \\ -1 & -5 \end{bmatrix}u
$$

with

$$
u(0)=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
u'(0) = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Okay I tried to create a $u$ vector but couldn't. And believe I can't get $\frac{du}{dt}$ by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $A$ right?  Since matrix $A$ multiplied by $u$ gives the second derivate, not matrix 
$A$ multiplied by the first derivative.

What to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent method without (explicitly) using eigenvalues, as the matrix is symmetric:

Writing $u=(u_1,u_2)^T$ the d.e. is equivalent to:

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2 u_1}{d t^2}&=-5u_1-u_2\\
\frac{d^2 u_2}{d t^2}&=-u_1-5u_2\\
\end{align}

Consider instead $u_1+u_2$, and $u_1-u_2$,

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2 }{d t^2}(u_1+u_2)&=-6(u_1+u_2)\\
\frac{d^2 }{d t^2}(u_1-u_2)&=-4(u_1-u_2)\\
\end{align}

Thus $$u_1+u_2=A\cos(t\sqrt{6})+B\sin(t\sqrt{6})$$

and $$u_1-u_2=C\cos(2t)+D\sin(2t)$$

Thus

\begin{align}
u_1&=\frac{1}{2}(A\cos(t\sqrt{6})+B\sin(t\sqrt{6})+C\cos(2t)+D\sin(2t))\\
u_2&=\frac{1}{2}(A\cos(t\sqrt{6})+B\sin(t\sqrt{6})-C\cos(2t)-D\sin(2t))\\
\end{align}

$u(0)=(1,0)^T \implies \frac{1}{2}(A+C)=1$ and $\frac{1}{2}(A-C)=0$, so $A=C=1$.

$u'(0)=(0, 0)^T \implies \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{6}B+2D)=0$ and $\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{6}B-2D)=0$, so $B=D=0$.

Thus the solution is:

$$\begin{pmatrix} u_1\\u_2 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} \cos{t\sqrt{6}}+\cos{2t}\\\cos{t\sqrt{6}}-\cos{2t} \end{pmatrix}$$

---

**Alternatively** we can follow the clever answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/373642/128967) by user: Start wearing purple.

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} -5 & -1\\-1 & -5\end{pmatrix}$$

A is symmetric so we can diagonalize it with an orthogonal matrix $P$ whose columns are eigenvectors. The eigenvalues of $A$ are found by solving $\det(\lambda I-A)=0$, which gives $(\lambda+5)^2-1=0$, i.e. $\lambda=-4$ or $\lambda=-6$. Plugging back in lambda and solving for $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=0$, gives two eigenvectors $(1, 1)^T$ and $(1, -1)^T$. So take $$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

As you can check $P$ is orthogonal, $P^TP=PP^T=I$. Then $$PAP^T=\begin{pmatrix}-6 & 0 \\ 0 & -4\end{pmatrix}=D$$

So if we act on our differential equation by $P^T$ then we have that

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}P^T \vec{u}=PA{u}=DP^T\vec{u}$$

Let $\vec{v}=P^T \vec{u}$, then we have the new differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\vec{v}=D\vec{v}$$

with new initial conditions $\vec{v}(0)=P^T \vec{u}(0)$ and  $\vec{v}'(0)=P^T \vec{u}'(0)$. This decouples into:

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2 v_1}{d t^2}&=-6v_1\\
\frac{d^2 v_2}{d t^2}&=-4v_2\\
\end{align}

We can solve the way we did before $\textit{or}$ to keep everything in terms of matrices and using that $f(\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2))=\operatorname{diag}(f(\lambda_1),f(\lambda_2))$ we can say that:

$$\vec{v}=\cos\left(t\sqrt{\strut-D} \right)\vec{v}(0)+\left(\sqrt{\strut-D}\right)^{-1}\sin\left(t\sqrt{\strut-D} \right)\vec{v}'(0)$$

Using that $P\vec{v}=\vec{u}$ we find that

\begin{align}
\vec{u}&=P\cos\left(t\sqrt{\strut-D} \right)P^T\vec{u}(0)+P\left(\sqrt{\strut-D}\right)^{-1}\sin\left(t\sqrt{\strut-D} \right)P^T\vec{u}'(0)\\
&=\cos\left(t\sqrt{\strut-A} \right)\vec{u}(0)+\left(\sqrt{\strut-A}\right)^{-1}\sin\left(t\sqrt{\strut-A} \right)\vec{u}'(0)\\
&=\cos\left(t\sqrt{\strut-A} \right)\vec{u}(0)
\end{align}

using that $P^T=P^{-1}$, and $f(PDP^{-1})=f(D)$. Of course it will be easier to evaluate $P\cos\left(t\sqrt{\strut-D} \right)P^T\vec{u}(0)$ which is

\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t\sqrt{6}) & 0 \\ 0 & \cos{2t}\end{pmatrix} \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} \cos{t\sqrt{6}}+\cos{2t}\\\cos{t\sqrt{6}}-\cos{2t} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: I didn't understand how you switched to cosines and sines

Comment: @Xenidia Let $x=u_1+u_2$, then the solution to $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x=-ax$, where $a>0$ is $x=A\sin{t\sqrt{a}}+B\cos{t\sqrt{a}}$. In this case $a=6$. For the other equation, $a=4$. As it so happens if you solve $\det(\lambda I-A)=0$, you'll find that the eigenvalues are $\lambda=-4$ and $\lambda=-6$, which is not a coincidence.

Comment: @Xenidia Is there anything else unclear? I can try link you to a solution to the equation $y''=-y$ if you like?